# Crontab not working for python

Tags: python, linux, scheduled-tasks, cron

I am trying to set a cron task for running a python script everyday at a specific time. Here is my `crontab -e`:

```
53 16 * * * python /code/4dlife/pythonscript.py
```

and I set this at 16:52 and waited and watched but nothing came up on the terminal. I checked `nano CRON /var/log/syslog` but it was empty.

What am I doing wrong? Can I see the script running on the same terminal as I have open? If not, where else can I see the output? BUT FIRST, I need to make it work.

Note:

1. I have `#!/usr/bin/env python` on top of my python script
2. I am running this on a virtual box with linux installed.

Comment: Does the script produce anything (i.e. file or dir) that you can check for to see if it worked?  I'm assuming you've already looked since you posted this question, but just checking anyway.  Is your python set up correctly?  We had an issue with one of our *nix boxes where python wasn't set properly and `/usr/bin/env python` didn't work.  Have you tried just `/usr/bin/python`?

Comment: check whether it is running using `ps aux|grep crontab`

Comment: @jared yes it works. and yes, the script works fine when I'm manually running it. I don't know what's happening with cron. :/

Comment: @itzmeontv yes I ran it already and the output is `root       939     1  0 15:54 ?        00:00:00 cron
ubuntu    2306  2186  0 15:57 pts/0    00:00:00 nano testcron.sh
ubuntu    2307  2186  0 15:57 pts/0    00:00:00 nano testcron.sh
ubuntu    2308  2186  0 15:57 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/sh ./testcron.sh
ubuntu    2309  2308  0 15:57 pts/0    00:00:00 nano testingcron`

Comment: when I run `ps -ef | grep cron | grep -v grep`

Comment: `cron` does not have access to your terminal - any output produced by the script will, in most default configurations, be mailed to the user under whose account the `cron` job was submitted.

Answer (score 1):

Use the exact path of your python executable in your crontab:

```
     53 16 * * * /usr/bin/python /code/4dlife/pythonscript.py
```

This way you can be certain that your crontab knows where to find python.

A way to debug scripts that run automatically is writing to syslog :

```
    import syslog

    syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_ERR, "---SCRIPT START---")
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your script work correctly in the terminal? I mean, when you type :

python /code/4dlife/pythonscript.py

Does the result appear?

Comment: Yes! Obviously it does!

Answer (score 0):

I used to have problems with Python in cron, but they were solved as I began to use virtualenv/virtualenvwrapper + pyenv .

Since them, I have used cron running the command with Python's full path, like

```
53 16 * * * /usr/bin/python /code/4dlife/pythonscript.py
```

. To get the full path, run in the shell

```
$ which python
```

and use the path as I showed.

The difference is that, in my case, the Python binary is located on a specific folder (`~/.virtualenv/<env-name>/bin/python`).